# Cocoapods vendored frameforks cause "Multiple commands produce ..." error

Tags: expo, cocoapods, podspec, xcframework, expo-module

I am developing an `Expo` iOS module and need to use frameworks provided by a company. I have specified my framework files like this in the `podspec` file:

```
s.vendored_frameworks =
  'Frameworks/EnQualify.xcframework',
  'Frameworks/IDVerification_arm64.xcframework'
```

After running `pod install`, frameworks are listed double like this under `Pod -> Development Pods`:

[image: Lsited framworks under Development Pods]

When try to build the project I get this error:

```
Multiple commands produce '.../Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/EnquraModule/EnquraModule.framework/Headers/EnQualify-Swift.h'

Multiple commands produce '.../Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/EnquraModule/EnquraModule.framework/Headers/EnVerify.h'

Multiple commands produce '.../Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/EnquraModule/EnquraModule.framework/Headers/IDVerification-Swift.h'

Multiple commands produce '.../Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/EnquraModule/EnquraModule.framework/Headers/IDVerify.h'
```

If I add the framework by listing it as a dependency it doesn't give error:

```
s.dependency 'EnVerify', '1.3.14.2'
```

But this time the framework can't locate the Alamofire dependency at runtime and my app crashes although it is located at the path where it says it can't find it,

```
dyld[1235]: Symbol not found: __ZN5swift34swift50override_conformsToProtocolEPKNS_14TargetMetadataINS_9InProcessEEEPKNS_24TargetProtocolDescriptorIS1_EEPFPKNS_18TargetWitnessTableIS1_EES4_S8_E
  Referenced from: <585CB2CE-BF96-3640-8199-AF873BD30339> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A45664A4-6079-49C8-B8F3-402131DD8316/ortakhisse.app/Frameworks/EnQualify.framework/EnQualify
  Expected in:     <AEBE2340-E54C-3254-B4EB-FFA0D7B4A7A7> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A45664A4-6079-49C8-B8F3-402131DD8316/ortakhisse.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
```

So what I need is add the framework manually without "multiple commands" error.

How can I fix this?

I am using Mac OS X Sonoma 14.2.1 and Xcode 15.0.1

Comment: Are frameworks without `arm64` compiled for another architecture (`x86` or something)?

Comment: They are compiled for arm64.